# Display superscript in title tag of html head

Tags: html, css, unicode, utf-8, title

I need to display superscripted **MC** in the `title` tag in the `html head`.
So far I am trying to display that with \uD83C\uDD6A according to the unicode character set in this [page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F16A/index.htm) .

So I am able to see superscripted **MC** in my chrome browser when I load the web page.
But it's not visible in any other chrome in other peoples MAC or windows.

Since we cannot use `css` style or `<sup>` in title `tag`.

What could be a solution for achieving the same?

Comment: I found an alternative. Posted it in my answer.

Comment: Do you have the live example, so I could take a look at the issue? Maybe there is something else messing with the entities.

Comment: Check out this link - https://slce.canada.q-aggregator.com/
Switch language to see MC in title of the tab. In my Chrome Mac I am able to see correctly in both the cases. But many people see boxes in case of french.

Comment: @Sparky any update on a solution?

Comment: Have you tried every solution in my answer?

Comment: Still Not Working.

But out of curiosity, what can be the reason that it's visible in my, your and few other peoples pc but not in other pc's. Checked this behaviour in Mac and Windows.

Comment: As I said before. Could be a `font` issue. `Language` issue. `System language/font`. Your browser and system has to support it. Also, Does your friend use a recent or outdated version? It's hard to state the problem, if I can't look at his system. Keep trying on different systems. And in the end you have to state for yourself if that 0.5% of your audience is really that important for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<title>&#127338; or &#x1f16a; or </title>
```

Or:

```
document.title = "&#127338; or &#x1f16a; or ";
```

**Alternative** is:

```
document.title = '\uD83C\uDD6A';
```

If none of these are visible, it's probably a **font** issue on the browser itself. Utf-8 is widely supported.

---

### EDIT

#### Ensure you are setting your charset:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

The UTF-8 character set supports all languages. But just in case..

#### Add a language to your html:

```
<html lang="en">
```

All language codes can be found [here](http://xml.coverpages.org/iso639a.html).

### Will update when I find more information on this matter...

In the end, formatting the `title` tag is a time consuming activity.

Is the **MC** character really important? Does it add anything valuable to the SERP (Search Engine Results Page)?

> **MC** in superscript is used as a trademark sign in, for example, Quebec, Canada.
>
> In Canada, there is no legal obligation to use the ® , TM, MC or MD
> symbols. It is however recommend to use ® (registered trade-mark) or
> MD (marque de commerce déposée) in association with your registered
> trade-marks. Symbols TM (trade-mark) or MC (marque de commerce) can be
> used in association with your other trade-marks whether an application
> has been filed or not. These symbols remind consumers and your
> competitors that you are the owner of the trade-marks in question.
>
> [Above was found here](https://www.guymuzzo.com/en/faq/can-i-use-%C2%AE-tm-tm-or-mc-symbols-next-my-trade-mark)

Comment: Both  &#x1f16a; and &#127338; are showing as text but MC is showing in my mac. It's not showing in my friends mac just like before.

Comment: I'm researching it now, please be patient for an update.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it could be a font issue. If a certain character is not available for a font, it either returns a blank, the html entity or a symbol with a question mark. I'm going to try and find a solution for you.

Comment: @nktkarnany Why does it have to be **MC** and not **TM** or the **R** if it's a registered trademark. Are you based in Quebec? - out of curiosity

Comment: In the english version I am using _TM_ but in the french version the client has asked to use _MC_.

Comment: @nktkarnany Could you try that **alternative** one? `document.title = '\uD83C\uDD6A';`

Comment: @nktkarnany The example you provided on [your link](https://slce.canada.q-aggregator.com), works just fine for me though. Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to an old [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114477/how-do-i-correctly-insert-unicode-in-an-html-title-using-javascript), you should use `&#x1f16a;` when using it directly in your title-tag.

Comment: Not working! I tried placing the &#x1f16a; and &#127338; in place of it. It displays the text  - &#x1f16a; and &#127338; but not MC.

Comment: @nktkarnany That's odd, I get a little rectangle when I try that. Can you explain how you are putting this in the title?

Comment: @MrLister Are you using Safari, Chrome, Opera, etc ?

Comment: @MrLister I am setting the title using the Angular 4 Title service like this -

For English - 
*this.titleService.setTitle("SmartLabel\u2122 Extract");*
// prints TM in superscript

For French - 
*this.titleService.setTitle("Extraction pour SmartLabel\uD83C\uDD6A");*
// prints MC in superscript but only in my Mac not others Mac or Windows. 
In others case it's showing box just like yours and when I place 
&#x1f16a; and &#127338; it shows the text as is. No boxes.

Comment: Another thing - TM is displaying correctly but MC is not getting displayed correctly. It shows up as boxes.